# applet security policy on Mac OS [edit: not policy after all]

Tags: java, macos, security, applet, policy

This is gonna be a big mess to explain, but if anyone has any pointer, Please share!

From an applet I'm calling a 3rd parity lib which uses JNI do fetch some info in an OS specific manner. I don't know what it calls since I don't have the code and support isn't very responsive.
The thing is, all works well on windows (not just my machine) but on Mac OS one of the lib's methods throws a lib specific exception (a code and a "Cannot complete" ~message). It seems to be a security related issue since the method works when I call it from within init().

The jar with my applet is self-signed, the library has 4 more jars that are signed by the vendor. The lib's method is called from within an "AccessController.doPrivileged" block as an applet method that is called from JavaScript - and this all works, but on windows only.

On Mac this call from JavaScript to the applet method that calls the lib's method gets the exception.

Here is what I tried:

I moved the lib's method call in init() just for the test and it works ok, only **without** an "AccessController.doPrivileged" block.
I tried starting a Thread in init() (in start() as well):
- using a timer to have the Thread calls the lib's method every 10sec works fine and I can get the updated reply troughs a String buffer - this isn't a preferred  solution.
- but if I use a flag in the thread so that the applet method can return the result it throws the same exception.

Here is the code in my applet's method:

```
checkRunner.refreshWindowsList = true;
while (checkRunner.refreshWindowsList) {
    try {           
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Ignoring exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
return checkRunner.windowsTitles;
```

and in the Thread's run method:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        if (refreshWindowsList) {
            windowsTitles = getWindowsTitlesPrivileged();
            //windowsTitles = getWindowsTitles();
            refreshWindowsList = false;
        }
        Thread.sleep(300);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Ignoring exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

I don't understand how just passing a flag can cause the different results.

Furthermore, it seems that when the applet is created from JavaScript code all of it is sandboxed and the lib's method throws the exception even from init() ... again only on Mac OS.

If anyone made it this far - Thank You : )

Comment: *"If anyone made it this far - Thank You : )"*  You're welcome, but I made it further, to the first instance of '?' on this page, which interestingly, is not in your post.  That leads me to the question - What is your question?  A second question for you.  Why is it so vital to have this app. wrapped in a browser - what does the browser bring to it (besides problems)?

Comment: Well yes, sorry for lack of a question mark.

Comment: I guess my main question is how can I get around this problem or at least if anyone has any info on why permission on Mac OS would differ so much from windows

Comment: And the applet is part of a web app and it needs to be possible to integrate it in the interface - call some applet methods from JavaScript. Which I don't know how to do, or if it's possible, with Java web start.

Comment: *"call some applet methods from JavaScript."*  Oh yes there it is, mentioned right in your 2nd paragraph.  (While I read the last line, I did not necessarily read all the lines in between.  My bad.)  I have no immediate inspirations on this problem, but if I think of anything, I'll pop back in.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, even thought I highly doubt this is a common problem...

It turns out that the issue is not security related after all. The problem originates because of a quite inexplicable (to me) behaviour of the 3rd parity library - whenever the problematic method is called, even in a separate thread, and in the main thread their is a loop to wait for the answer - the exception is thrown.

So the following code fails, but when the sleep line at the end is removed it works ok. This happens no matter where the code is, init() or a method called from JavaScript - the behaviour is the same.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
            public String run() {
                callTheMehod();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();

try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (exce....) {}
```

I ended up splitting the code into two methods called from JavaScript - one that calls the library method, putting the result in a volatile String and another that simply returns this volatile String. In JavaScript their is a waiting loop between the two. Strange thing is that if this loop has an interval that is very short - and the method to check for the result is called too often the library method fails again.

So it seems whenever there is too much load on the main thread the exception is thrown. This is quite inexplicable to me but since the library is using JNI I guess is a lot that could go wrong.